# Using xcopy instead of robocopy for wildcarded files

Tags: robocopy, xcopy

I'm working on an old 2003 server and I want to copy a folder for specific files while also retaining the folder structure. 
**Note: I am not allowed to install or add robocopy onto this server.**

The command that I use on another server is usually something like this.

```
robocopy Application Application_small *.txt /E
```

This, of course, gives me a new directory with nothing but the `.txt` files and the same folder structure.

But of course, **robocopy** isn't on Server 2003. However, **xcopy** does exist. Is there an equivalent switch that I can use to get the same kind of result as **robocopy**?

Comment: I can't install software onto this server.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question was found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/112537/windows-7-move-only-files-of-a-given-extension-while-preserving-folder-structu).

```
xcopy Application\*.txt Application_small /s
```